# Small residue in ${\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given $r$ a element of $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^*$, let $d$ be the order of $r$.

What's the smallest number $D$ for which if $d>D$, then there exists an element of the cyclic subgroup $\langle r\rangle$  that is $<log^2(n)$ (except, of course, 1).
It's better if this element is another generator of $\langle r\rangle$.

Any partial result or reading advice are welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not clear what $<<log(n)$ means.

Comment: Perhaps better: Given $\epsilon>0$ does there exist $D$ such that for every $d>D$, every multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^*$ with elements of order exactly $d$ has a representant $r\in\mathbb N$ of order exactly $d$ and size $r<\epsilon \log n$. (I think the answer is "no such $D$ exists for arbitrarily large $\epsilon$".)

Comment: $D$ depends on $n$ . Of course if $D$ doesn't depend on $n$ , then for $n$ large $r<r^D<n$ for $r$ small enough and superior to $log^2(n)$ for exemple.

Comment: Sorry, (the ambiguity of $<<\log n$ made me believe that it should work for all $n$)! (The ambiguity remains, see the comment of GH.)

Comment: Right it wasn't clear sorry ...let say $<log^2(n)$ .

Comment: Emmanuel, you can edit your answer and clarify it.

Comment: A very stupid answer: for $n$ fixed,  make the list of all orders of all elements up to your bound and choose $D$ such that all orders $>D$ possible for elements of $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^*$ are in your list.

Comment: Another suggestion: You could perhaps use the standard notation $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^*$ for multiplicative groups.

Comment: It's done thank you for your comment. But I still don't have an answer :(

Comment: The question is unclear. The elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ are residue classes. It does not make sense to say that a residue class is smaller than $\log^2(n)$.